# Chromium-browser version 83 on Raspbian

Tags: selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do browser automation on a raspberry pi 3b using selenium and chromedriver.

I am using chromedriver version 9.3.2 which apparently needs chrome version 83. I now want to install chromium-browser version 83 onto my raspberry pi in order to successfully run my browser-automation. Can anyone tell me, where I can find and install chromium-browser 83, or where I can find a newer version of chromedriver which will work with chromium-browser version 86?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a/the solution to this problem.

Since I started using selenium for browser automation I always tried to install certain versions of chromedriver as well as chromium-browser as I have read that this specific combination seems to be working for raspbian.

As it turns out, there is a possibility to always have a working latest-version setup:

Run:

`sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`

to get the latest chromedriver, then  run:

`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

to get the latest version of the chromium browser.

This should be it for successfully running selenium in Python.
Date today (29.12.2020) versions for chromedriver and chromium-browser are
86.0.4240.197-rpt1.

Hope this is helpfull.